# Delay java.util.Timer by another x seconds

Tags: java, timer, thread-sleep

I'm trying to run a `java.util.Timer` every three seconds, and I need to delay it by another 2 at a certain condition. To check whether this could be achived using `Thread.sleep()`, I wrote the code below.

```
Timer t = new Timer();

t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (true) { //When this is false timer should continue at 3 second interval.
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000); //Delay by another 2 seconds.
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(new Date());
    }
}, 0, 3000); //Trigger every 3 seconds.
```

I'm expecting to print timestamps with a difference of 5 seconds. But I'm getting it with a 3 second difference.

```
Tue Sep 18 15:08:17 IST 2018
Tue Sep 18 15:08:20 IST 2018
Tue Sep 18 15:08:23 IST 2018
Tue Sep 18 15:08:26 IST 2018
Tue Sep 18 15:08:29 IST 2018
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sleep of 2 seconds is only simulating 2 seconds of work within the 3 seconds interval between `TimerTask` triggers. So around 1 second after your sleep, your timer will kick in again.

Try doing a sleep of 5 seconds instead.

However, remember that delaying in this way is not very stable. The Timer will consider all the tasks behind schedule and trigger them sequentially as soon as the previous one finishes. It might be better to cancel the tasks and reschedule them to 5 seconds interval if that is what you really want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is just delaying the print of the date by 2 seconds. It will still be at a 3 second interval.

Eg: With start date x:

Without the Thread.sleep, you will print at:

```
x, x + 3, x + 6, x + 9
```

With the Thread.sleep, you will print at:

```
x + 2, x + 3 + 2, x + 6 + 2, x + 9 + 2
```

which is equal to:

```
x + 2, x + 5, x + 8, x + 11 etc
```

So there is still a 3 second delay between each print.

See documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

> Corresponding to each Timer object is a single background thread that
>   is used to execute all of the timer's tasks, sequentially. Timer tasks
>   should complete quickly. If a timer task takes excessive time to
>   complete, it "hogs" the timer's task execution thread. This can, in
>   turn, delay the execution of subsequent tasks, which may "bunch up"
>   and execute in rapid succession when (and if) the offending task
>   finally completes.

The same thread will be used to process each execution of your timer task. When the task is run and it does not complete in time before the timer fires the next execution of the task, the next execution will be delayed until the previous execution completes. The behaviour is similar to a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor with a threadpool size of 1.

Comment: No, the Timer only uses one thread. If the first task takes longer than 3 seconds (for example 5 seconds), the second task won't start before the first task finishes.

Comment: Timer is using only a single thread. Verified it using `Thread.currentThread().hashCode()`.

Comment: Ah ok, you are right. From the documentation: Corresponding to each Timer object is a single background thread that is used to execute all of the timer's tasks, sequentially. Timer tasks should complete quickly. If a timer task takes excessive time to complete, it "hogs" the timer's task execution thread. This can, in turn, delay the execution of subsequent tasks, which may "bunch up" and execute in rapid succession when (and if) the offending task finally completes. Im going to edit my answer to reflect this part.

Comment: Yep. So the output you indicated is expected too (I reordered them purposely):  x + 2, x + 3 + 2, x + 6 + 2, x + 9 + 2.... if however the sleep is changed to 5, then it becomes: x + 5, x + 10, x + 15, x + 20 ... (the delay of the timer task gets ignored from after the first task because they are all behind and 'bunched up'